# Will HHVM be able to run PHP7

Tags: hhvm, php-7

I know that PHP7 has a new compiler that is almost as fast as HHVM, but I am just curious if HHVM will also be able to run PHP7 as well as PHP5.

I can't find any details on this.
Everything I find is just a HHVM vs PHP7
Also for that matter can anyone find what versions of PHP5 will run on HHVM.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes, we intend to support the new PHP7 language features in HHVM. It's on the HHVM team's roadmap for this half. Most of the features, such as the [null coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary), are backwards-compatible, so we can just add them. A couple of them have backwards-compatiblity issues, such as [uniform variable syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax); the team is still evaluating what we want to do with this. We'd like to find a way to maintain compatibility with *both* PHP5 and PHP7, probably by making these backwards-compatibility-breaking options selectable via an INI option, or something like that.

Comment: Awesome, This is great news.  I would suggest a blog page or a some sort of official page announcing PHP7 compatibility with Information regarding php7's new compiler and how it works with hhvm, features, workarounds, and benchmarks, etc.  Then post it here.   Thanks